# How to add new object to track in Ninject after Application_Started?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

Is it possible to add a new object that Ninject should be responsible for (lifetime, injection etc.) in an ASP.NET application after the `Application_Started` event is fired?

My application needs to dynamically designate objects that should be tracked well after the application is started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the `Kernel` object created at `Application_Start` either by a static reference or [preferably] by use of a [Common Service Locator](http://kohari.org/2008/06/18/playing-nice-with-service-locators/), you should be able to call `Bind<T>()` on the object to update the context.

I haven't personally tried this, but it does comply with the class structure.

Comment: There's nothing preferable about CSL, though an M3 CSL is OK :P

Answer (score 0):

(Some of this addresses the other answer more than your question, but hope it helps overall) You don't really call `Bind<T>()` on object instances, you do that to register bindings which are then used in either resolving new instances via `Kernel.Get<T>()` or using `Kernel.Inject(@object)` to inject [typically properties only (as you're not constructing)] into an object not created under the control of Ninject.

While `Inject`ed objects will be activated etc., their scoping etc. doesnt always work in the same way. Perhaps you can expand on exactly what *specific* services you expect to gain other than property injection to clarify? (See the [cache and collect opus](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/) for details of lifetime management)