# How to instantiate a MEF exported object using Ninject?

Tags: dependency-injection, mef, ninject

My application is using MEF to export some classes from an external assembly. These classes are setup for constructor injection. The issue I am facing is that 
MEF is attempting to instantiate the classes when I try to access them. Is there a way to have Ninject take care of the instantiation of the class?

```
IEnumerable<Lazy<IMyInterface>> controllers = 
    mefContainer.GetExports<IMyInterface>();

// The following line throws an error because MEF is 
// trying to instantiate a class that requires 5 parameters
IMyInterface firstClass = controllers.First().Value;
```

### Update:

There are multiple classes that implement `IMyInterface` and I would like to select the one that has a specific name and then have Ninject create an instance of it. I'm not really sure if I want laziness.

```
[Export(typeof(IMyInterface))]
public class MyClassOne : IMyInterface {

     private MyRepository one;
     private YourRepository two;

     public MyClassTwo(MyRepository repoOne, YourRepository repoTwo) {
            one = repoOne;
            two = repoTwo;
     }         
}

[Export(typeof(IMyInterface))]
public class MyClassTwo : IMyInterface {

     private MyRepository one;
     private YourRepository two;

     public MyClassTwo(MyRepository repoOne, YourRepository repoTwo) {
            one = repoOne;
            two = repoTwo;
     }


}
```

Using MEF, I would like to get either `MyClassOne` or `MyClassTwo` and then have Ninject provide an instance of `MyRepository` and `YourRepository` (Note, these two are bound in a Ninject module in the main assembly and not the assembly they are in)

Comment: Does my answer do the job? If not, I'd like to make it better. Even if my answer is way off base and I cant give you a satisfactory answer, you should follow-up to maximise the value of your bounty as others will be guessing what bit is missing too... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [Ninject `Load` mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673492/how-to-use-ninject-in-constructor-injection-of-a-type-in-an-external-assembly/3680249#3680249) to get the exported classes into the mix, and the you either:

```
kernel.GetAll<IMyInterface>()
```

The creation is lazy (i.e., each impl of `IMyInterface` is created on the fly as you iterate over the above) IIRC, but have a look at the tests in the [source](http://github.com/ninject/ninject) (which is very clean and readable, you have no excuse :P) to be sure.

If you dont need the laziness, use LINQ's `ToArray` or `ToList` to get a `IMyInterface[]` or `List<IMyInterface>`

or you can use the low-level `Resolve()` family of methods (again, have a look in the tests for samples) to get the eligible services [if you wanted to do some filtering or something other than just using an instance - though binding metadata is probably the solution there]

Finally, if you can edit in an explanation of whether you need laziness per se or are doing it to illustrate a point. (and have a search for `Lazy<T>` here and in general wrt both Ninject and autofac for some samples - cant recall if there are any examples in the source - think not as it's still on 3.5)

EDIT: In that case, you want a bind that has:

```
Bind<X>().To<>().In...().Named( "x" );
```

in the registrations in your modules in the child assembly.

Then when you're resolving in the parent assembly, you use the `Kernel.Get<>` overload that takes a `name` parameter to indicate the one you want (no need for laziness, arrays or `IEnumerable`). The `Named` mechanism is a specific (just one or two helper extensions implement it in terms of the generalised concept) application of the  binding metadata concept in Ninject - there's plenty room to customise it if somethng beyond a simple name is insufficient.

If you're using MEF to construct the objects, you could use the [`Kernel.Inject()` mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646754/how-to-add-new-object-to-track-in-ninject-after-application-started/3680570#3680570) to inject properties. The problem is that either MEF or Ninject 
 - has to find the types (Ninject: generally via `Bind()` in `Module`s or via scanning extensions, after which one can do a `Resolve` to subset the bindings before instantiation - though this isnt something you normally do)
 - has to instantiate the types (Ninject: typically via a `Kernel.Get()`, but if you discovered the types via e.g. MEF, you might use the [`Kernel.Get(Type)` overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673492/how-to-use-ninject-in-constructor-injection-of-a-type-in-an-external-assembly/3680249#3680249) )
 - has to inject the types (Ninject: typically via a `Kernel.Inject()`, or implicit in the `Kernel.Get())

What's not clear to me yet is why you feel you need to mix and mangle the two - ultimately sharing duties during construction and constructor injection is not a core use case for either lib, even if they're both quite composable libraries. Do you have a constraint, or do you have critical benefits on both sides?

Comment: Updated answer with some more info. Also, could you provide the link to the test you're referring to. I can't seem to find them.

Comment: @Baddie: I reckon you updated the 'answer' :D I updated mine (with more questions!) Re the tests I'm referring to, I'd be doing a get of the ''full'' trunk and then doing a find in files for IEnumerable and/or the word lazy (think some of the `[Fact]`s have something like resolution should be lazy in the title) NB this isnt what you want any more based on your clarifications.

Comment: Although using the `Named` method works fine for me, I wouldn't be using MEF to discover these classes.

Comment: @Baddie: So are you sorted then? Do you need MEF in the picture or are you happy using just Ninject? Are you still looking for a pure MEF solution? Anything else unclear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExportFactory to create Instances
see docs here:

http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PartCreator

Your case would be slitly different
I would use Metadata and a custom attribute also

```
[ImportMany(AllowRecomposition=true)] 
    IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IMyInterFace, IMyInterfaceMetaData>> Controllers{ get; set; } 

public IMyInterface CreateControllerFor(string parameter)
{
var controller = Controllers.Where(v => v.Metadata.ControllerName == parameter).FirstOrDefault().CreateExport().Value; 
            return controller; 
}
```

or use `return Controllers.First()` without the Metadata

Then you can code the ninject parts around that or even stick with MEF
Hope this helps

Comment: The `ExportFactory` type is only available for Silverlight.