# How to use Ninject in constructor injection of a type in an external assembly

Tags: assemblies, ninject, constructor-injection

I am loading a type from an external assembly and want to create an instance of the type. However, this type/class is setup for constructor injection by objects currently being managed/bound by `Ninject`. How can I use `Ninject` to create an instance of this type and inject any constructor dependencies?

Below is how I get this type.

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll");
Type type = myAssembly.GetType("IMyType");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've created a `Kernel`, you should be able to create and have it resolved via:

```
kernel.Get(type)
```

.... then I read the question.... Assuming MyAssembly.dll has an implementation of IMyType, you need (in your main assembly) :-

```
kernel.Load( "MyAssembly.dll")
```

And in your dynamically loaded assembly:-

```
public class Module : StandardModule
{
    public override void Load()
    { 
        Bind<IMyType>().To<MyType>();
    }
}
```

And dont forget to see if MEF is the answer here, as you dont want to go writing reams of explicit plugin management and/or detection logic if you can help it (but if you're just doing straightforward stuff and are only doing the `Assembly.LoadFrom()` for the purposes of asking the question, you're probably still in Ninject's sweet spot.

Ditto, if you actually need to resolve an interface via `Assembly.GetType()`, you probably should be using something like `dynamic` to do the late binding you'll probably have to do (and before you know it you should be using a dynamic language or hosting a scriopting language)