# Is it possible to change how MEF creates imported objects?

Tags: c#, mef, ninject

I would like to use MEF to find my extensions but keep the responsibility for creating them to Ninject or a custom factory. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you edit this to explain what the difference is between this and [this older post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654703/how-to-instantiate-a-mef-exported-object-using-ninject) please and/or delete this?

Comment: The older post is more related to Ninject and here Ninject is just a detail. I'm more interested to know how to use a custom factory to create my exported objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the article:
"Export Providers and Custom factories with MEF", by Glenn Block
http://codebetter.com/blogs/glenn.block/archive/2008/11/30/export-providers-and-custom-factories-with-mef.aspx.

You can read some bits about possibilities to use custom factories.

In this article, you will see links to 2 other, by Matt Hawley:
"MEF + Factories", and "MEF + Factories Using an Export Provider"

Comment: Great posts indeed, although I didn't like the solution. It would be much nicer to have something similar to what they do in Ria Services. Ex: ExportFactory.Factory = new MyCustomFactory(); And that's it, I control the object creation :)